# What is the variance for a distribution of the average value of ONE roll of a six-sided fair dice (sample size N=1)?

Tags: probability, statistics

The distribution would be a flat line, so would the variance be 0? And if so, why is that?

Here is why I ask. Lets just say I did 6 samples of 1 roll and get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. Doing a standard deviation calculation for each roll is trivial because the sample value minus the mean of that sample is simply 0. So therefore the sum of squared deviates is also 0.

And thus I could extend this to the general case. A average value distribution for any population that has equal probabilities for each possible value of the random variable, would have a variance of 0 if sample size is taken to be 1.

Comment: What's an unfair single sided die by the way?

Comment: variance 0 would imply constant so the variance is definitely not zero for a fair dice

Comment: Look at your definition of variance and compute it.  The result is some number with probability $1$.  Just plug that in.  Computing $(\overline x)^2$ and $(\overline x)^2$ are not hard.

Comment: @MarkJoshi:  but this die has only one side.

Comment: Oh jeez huge mistake, I meant to say 6-sided dice. Thank you for hilariously trying to interpret what I asked though.

Answer (score 0):

You have a discrete random distribution with probability $\frac 16$ for each number from $1$ to $6$.  Can you compute the expectation?  That is just the average of all the numbers, which is $\overline x$.  Square it to get $(\overline x)^2$  Can you compute the average of the squares of all the numbers?  That is $\overline {x^2}$.  Now look up the formula for the variance and plug them in.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I roll a dice, then take the average value of that roll (which is of course the roll itself), and then find the distribution of all those individual rolls. What I am NOT doing is finding the average value of a sample size of TWO rolls because that would yield a normal distribution around the population mean of 3.5.

Comment: No, I understand exactly.  The first sentence is the probability distribution of one roll.  You are correct that the mean is $3.5$, so that is the $\overline x$ in your variance formula.  Now just add up the squares of the six possible rolls and divide by $6$ to get the mean of $x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

the mean is always 3.5. The mean itself is not a random variable other than in a degenerate sense. Yes, the mean has variance 0.

However, the sample mean of a sample of size 1 is different. Each roll will be different so the mean will simply be the sample. In this case, the variance is the variance of a fair die roll and will not be zero. The sample variance is not really defined for a draw of size 1.

Possibly you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Right, so if we were to create a sample distribution of sample means, it would be a straight line at the probability 1/6 with going through an x axis with values 1 through 6. Just like a histogram. The STANDARD ERROR of that sample mean distribution would certainly be non zero, but the variance/standard deviation for any particular sample would be 0.